# underscore and dash are not recognized in a variable

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, seo

I have the following rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([\da-z]+)/([\da-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?office=$1&page=$2&news_id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\da-z]+)/([\da-z]+)/?$ index.php?office=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

when I have an url like: www.test.com/media/continuous-training it doesn't send the continuous-training to the variable. If I don't use dash or underscore everything is fine.

I think the problem is in my regex in the rule, but not sure how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using `[W-]` in you character class that will match `[A-Za-z0-9_-]`

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?office=$1&page=$2&news_id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?office=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `-` and `_` to your character class. Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\da-z_-]+)/([\da-z_-]+) ...
```